# Converting JToken into a complex Object using ToObject

Tags: c#, json, class, object, json-deserialization

sorry for my bad english. But i need a little help with this method (ToObject)

I have this class

```
    namespace Proyects
    {
        public class AProductType
        {
            public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
            public string Product { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class AProduct
        {
            public AProductType A_ProductType { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class AProductPlantType
        {
            public string SerialNumberProfile { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class ToPlant
        {
            public List<AProductPlantType> A_ProductPlantType { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class AProductDescriptionType
        {
            public string Language { get; set; }
            public string Product { get; set; }
            public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class ToDescription
        {
            public List<AProductDescriptionType> A_ProductDescriptionType { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class Root
        {
            public AProduct A_Product { get; set; }
            public ToPlant to_Plant { get; set; }
            public ToDescription to_Description { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

I am currently using the Root one to save a Jtoken in there. But i cant save the data on the propieties from Root class.

For example:

```
var object= myJson.ToObject<Root>();
```

If i try to save data on the propiety Product from **AProductType**, i cant access there using using ToOject. I try someting like this

```
var object= myJson.ToObject<Root>().A_Product.A_ProductType.Product;
```

And dont work, object var become null. I need some way to save the data around this complex object saving then in the propietes from **Root**.

Really sorry for my english, Thanks!!!

Edit: Json file

```
{
  "A_Product": {
    "A_ProductType": {
      "CreationDate": "2020-01-17T00:00:00",
      "Product": "158"
    }
  },
    "to_Plant": {
        "A_ProductPlantType": [
          {
            "SerialNumberProfile": "E001"       
          }
        ]
      },
        "to_Description": {
        "A_ProductDescriptionType": [
          {
            "Language": "EN",
            "Product": "158",
            "ProductDescription": "Terminal LaP (nro de serie + equipo)"
          },
          {
            "Language": "ES",
            "Product": "158",
            "ProductDescription": "Terminal LaP"
          }
        ]
      } 
}
```

Edit 2:

```
private static List<string> retrieveData(JObject ob, List<Root> listaObjetos)
        {           
            List<string> ListaCodigoProducto = new List<string>();
            Root objetoRot = new Root();
            
            var A_Product = ob["A_Product"];

            if (A_Product.HasValues)
            {
                
                var validacion = ob["A_Product"]["A_ProductType"];
                            
                if (validacion.Type == JTokenType.Object)   
                {
                    
                    var objeto = validacion.ToObject<AProductType>();
                            
                    ListaCodigoProducto.Add(objeto.Product);

                    objetoRot.A_Product.A_ProductType.Product = objeto.Product;

                    listaObjetos.Add(objetoRot);
                }
```

When i try to save the product number on

```
 objetoRot.A_Product.A_ProductType.Product
```

It shows NullReference exception, i cant access to the propiety in the Root object

Comment: Since your english is not very good, maybe you can post json pls?

Comment: `myJson.ToObject Root()` is not valid C#.  This will not compile.  Can you edit your question to show the actual code you're using?  Also, can you post the JSON you're using that's failing to deserialize?  Having this information would make it a lot easier for us to help you debug this.

Comment: Done guys. Sorry, first time posting here

Comment: With the provided JSON, I'm not able to reproduce the problem.  If I say `Console.WriteLine(obj.A_Product.A_ProductType.Product);` it prints `158`, as expected.

Comment: added more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deserializing code is working just fine.  Your problem is that you're accessing objects that aren't there.

When you say `Root objetoRot = new Root();`, you are creating a new, empty `Root`.  Its `A_Product` value will be `null`.  A few lines down, you are saying `objetoRot.A_Product.A_ProductType.Product = objeto.Product;`.  But you can't get `objetoRot.A_Product.A_ProductType` because there is no `objetoRot.A_Product` to access properties on.

Comment: There is any way to access or save data on the AProductType properties using the Root class? If i want to save data from the Json, how i can put then in the properties?

Comment: @juanlopez The simplest way would be to modify your declarations to say stuff like `MyObjectType MyProperty {get; set;} = new MyObjectType();`.  That would ensure that the objects are initialized rather than starting out as `null`.

Comment: OMG it works!!! Thx Mason, I really appreciate your help